# Moving a Value From One Function to Another

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to learn the programming language. I created a quick website that converts temperature from fahrenheit to Celsius and I am using javascript to do the conversion.  I know that it does not have to be broken into two different functions but I though I would start simple and build towards more complex.  The code I am using to complete the conversion is:

```html
function toCelcius(){
 
 var temp = document.getElementById("tempConversion").value;

 var dif = calculate(temp);

 var c = (5/9) * dif;
 
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
 
}

function calculate(temp){
 
 var dif = temp - 32;
 
 document.getElementById("firstCalc").innerHTML = dif;

}
```

I know that NaN means not a number so I am assuming that the line, var dif = calculation(temp), is not defined properly.  Unfortunately, I do not understand why and could use your help understanding.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your HTML code aswell, we can't reproduce the problem without it

Comment: Also, please specify your problem because I can't really make out what the question is

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/paraselixir/0mx4gj41/  you can check working code here

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculate(temp){
    var dif = temp - 32;
    document.getElementById("firstCalc").innerHTML = dif;
    return dif; // return the value here...
}

function toCelcius(){
    var temp = document.getElementById("tempConversion").value;
    var dif = calculate(temp); // returned value will be assigned in "dif"
    var c = (5/9) * dif;
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function **calculate(temp)** is not returning a value which is being needed. As a result, **dif** will be **undefined** and it will give you **NaN** when you perform any arithmetic operations there.

Update you function like this -

```
function calculate(temp){

    var dif = temp - 32;

    document.getElementById("firstCalc").innerHTML = dif;
    return dif;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting a value back from a function, instead of setting a variable, try using `return` like I did. Note that in `calculate()`, the variable doesn't have to be named `dif`. Really try to understand what's happening here, as a more complete understanding will help you in the long run.

```js
function toCelcius(){
 
 var temp = document.getElementById("tempConversion").value;

 var dif = calculate(temp);

 var c = (5/9) * dif;
 
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = c;
 
}

function calculate(temp){
 
 var dif = temp - 32;
 
 document.getElementById("firstCalc").innerHTML = dif;
  
    return dif;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tempConversion"></input>
<br/>
<button type="button" onClick="toCelcius();">Convert</button>
<br/>
<span id="firstCalc"></span>
<br/>
<span id="answer"></span>
```

Essentially, since you didn't use `return`, no matter whet you set `dif` to (not to mention that using `var` separated the two `dif` variables, so the first one wouldn't get set), it would immediately get set to what you returned from `calculate()`-- which was `undefined`.